# Should I write $x (f(x))^{-1}$ with less parenthesis.

Tags: notation

In this case, $x$ and $f(x)$ belong to a multiplicative group.  I would like to write $x f(x)^{-1}$ instead of $x(f(x))^{-1}$. I figured that I could explain once what I mean by $x f(x)^{-1}$ and then use it freely after that. Is this acceptable?

Comment: By $f(x)^{-1}$, do you mean $f^{-1}(x)$ or $1\over f(x)$?

Comment: Introducing notation and then using it consequently in a correct way should be ok. Just avoid ambiguity to already existing notation.

Comment: $xf(x)^{-1}$ (or $x\,f(x)^{-1}$ with a small space) seems fine to me as long as $x$ is an element of the group and $f$ is a function.  $x(f(x))^{-1}$ looks superfluous a bit.  Another option would be $x\cdot f(x)^{-1}$ where $\cdot$ denotes the multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem recently and I decided to opt for brackets,
as in the expression
$$
\Delta^{abb} =  [f(bb)]^{-1} f(b) [f(1)]^{-1} f(b) [f(ab)]^{-1} f(a)
 [f(ab)]^{-1} f(abb)
$$
An alternative solution is to have an additive notation for the group (even if it is not commutative, but better warn the reader), which would give
$$
\Delta^{abb} = - f(bb) + f(b)-f(1)+f(b)-f(ab)+ f(a)-f(ab) + f(abb)
$$

Comment: In my case, I wanted to emphasize that the general theory worked for all groups and then I wanted to handle the special case of finite abelian groups using additive notation. Judging from the other comments about my question, as much as I wish I didn't have to do it, It looks like brackets is the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative ist just using maps without argument variables, like
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{id}{id}
\id f^{-1}
$$
if you mean the product, or
$$
\id \circ f^{-1}
$$
if you mean the composition of $\id$ and the inverse of $f$.
Or did you mean
$$
\id / f
$$